# Rails 5: связать 2 модели для "старой" MSSQL базы

Tags: sql-server, ruby-on-rails, model

Есть база которая разрабатывалась вначале на Access, затем мигрировала на MSSQLServer и на которой "крутится" ПО, но также встал вопрос выводить часть данных через web

- 2 таблицы:

```html
[dbo].[ELO_USERS](
 [USRNAME] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [USRPWD] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [USRID] [numeric](10, 0) NOT NULL,
 [DATE_] [datetime] NULL,
 [IBD_ARX] [numeric](6, 0) NULL
)
[dbo].[LDV_ADD_INFO](
 [UNICODE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [CODE] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 [VOL] [varchar](255) NULL
)
```

ключевые поля [USRID] и [UNICODE] соответственно
, где [dbo].[LDV_ADD_INFO] содержит дополнительную информацию, в том числе и по пользователям,
[dbo].[LDV_ADD_INFO].[UNICODE] == '$user$' + [dbo].[ELO_USERS].[USRID]
, т.е. я не могу связать unicode и usrid "напрямую", т.к. usrid нужно модифицировать

- Создал 2 модели, контроллер и вьюху

```html
Model:  
class EloUser < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'USRID'
  
  def id
    '$user$' + read_attribute(:USRID).to_i.to_s
  end
  
  def informations
    UserInformation.where(UNICODE: self.id)
  end
end

class UserInformation < ApplicationRecord
  self.table_name = "ldv_add_info"
end

Controller 
class EloUsersController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @elo_users = EloUser.all
  end
end

View
- @elo_users.each do |u|
  %p
    = u.to_json
    - u.informations.each do |i|
      = i.to_json
```

все отлично, но получается, что для получения информации по пользователям (u.informations.each) создается N запросов к MSSQL Serverу на страницу (по количеству пользователей)

через 2 дня мучений мана закончилась и прошу помочь:
 связать эти две таблицы через has_many <-> belongs_to

и тогда станет возможным контроллер скорректировать на:
@elo_users = EloUser.all.includes(:informations)
и как следствие к базе данных был бы 1 запрос.

ну или подсказать другое возможное решение :)

Спасибо!

Comment: Выкинуть ActiveRecord и взять [Sequel](http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/advanced_associations_rdoc.html)?

Answer (score -1):

Не уверен, что правильно понял всю глубину вопроса, но возможно поможет *связать эти две таблицы через has_many <-> belongs_to*, путем указания опций для связи *belongs_to* в модели *UserInformation*:

```
belongs_to :elo_user, foreign_key: "UNICODE", primary_key: "USRNAME"
```

см. [Опции для belongs_to](http://rusrails.ru/active-record-associations#options-for-belongs-to)

Comment: Определённо поняли неправильно. *"я не могу связать unicode и usrid "напрямую", т.к. usrid нужно модифицировать"* Т. е. там нужен, в разных случаях, `INNER JOIN t2 ON t2.id = func(t1.t2_id)` или `WHERE t2.id = func(?)`. Это не совсем чистый `belongs_to` и потребует в ActiveRecord таких забористых хаков, что проще выкинуть его вовсе.